# The existence of an irreducible factor of degree at least $k$ of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$ be a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ of degree $n$. Suppose that for some $k (0 < k < n)$ and some prime $p: p∤a_n; p∤a_k; p|a_i$ for all $0≤i≤k-1$; and $p^2∤a_0$. 
Show that $f$ has a factor $g$ of degree at least $k$ that is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.
It looks quite similar to Eisenstein's criterion, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: The proof is very similar to Eisenstein theorem's proof itself, you should show your effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Suppose $f=g h = \sum_i g_i x^i \cdot \sum_j h_j x^j. \quad$  As $p \mid a_0$ but $p^2 \not \mid a_0=g_0 h_0$ WLOG $p \mid g_0$ and $p \not \mid h_0$.  Next $p \mid a_1 = g_1h_0+g_0 h_1 \implies p \mid g_1.\quad$  Continue till $p \mid g_{k-1}$ but $p \not \mid g_k\implies \deg(g) \ge k$.